# Defining cusstom tokenizer in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

This is how i am trying to define a custom tokenizer in es

"pattern" :"[\-s+]",

but when i run this i get the response as shown below

"pattern" : """[-s+]""",

notice in the output i get additional quotes :  "pattern" : """[-s+]""",in the begenninng and the end, if we dont have to use any escape characters this works fine, but when using escape character this results in double quotes being appended, any help?

Answer (score 0):

`\` Is a reserved Lucene operator, you have to escape it.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html

Please try this way

```
PUT test_varun
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern":"[\\-s+]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If doesnt make it please attach an example input/output to reproduce in my end.